# Graph path finding problem with no overlapping edges

Tags: algorithm, graph

I am new to graph path finding problems, and i need an algorithm to cover all vertices of a graph without overlapping edges.
I think it is similar to traveling salesman problem.
I don't need to find shortest path, any path with any cost will be fine.
I just have two conditions
1. All vertices should be covered(each vertex is a 2D point). 
2. There should be no overlapping edges.(line should not cross each other like an "X".)
And the graph is 2D.
Please help

Comment: This problem is called the hamiltonian path problem.

Comment: You are write, but i don't want one edge cross another edge. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Are nodes represented by 2d points? Is it a complete graph?

Comment: In your question you said: "no overlapping edge", in your comment you said: "edge don't cross each other". I think it requires some clarification, you can edit your question to describe your problem more clearly.